# Sending Ctrl_C over ssh

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, bash-trap

On many of my servers autofs is hung and a process is trying to access a mount, and while I ssh to the remote host the it hangs there until I press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from my keyboard

```
dew:~ # ssh  dew00922
```

but when I press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> its goes to the prompt

```
dew:~ # ssh  dew00922
^C-bash-3.2#
-bash-3.2#
```

I'm trying to send trap signal via the ssh but that also hangs

```
dew:~ # ssh  dew00922 'trap 2 && service autofs restart'
```

Any help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you ssh in, it's trying to run `/etc/profile` and then `~root/.profile` (or `~root/.bash_profile` or `~root/.bash_login`) and `~root/.bashrc`. One of those scripts runs a command that is trying to access a hung filesystem. When you press <kbd>^ C</kbd>, you're killing the script and getting a prompt from the bash on dew0922. At that point you are logged into dew00922 and can run commands. Any commands you run that try to access a hung filesystem will hang.

Comment: makes a lot of sense, so basically it has to fail.., thank you for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

`timeout` is the tool made for such problems:

```
ssh  dew00922 'timeout 2 service autofs restart'
```

See `man timeout` for more information